# ubuntu 18.04 making a pop sound on shutdown

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, sound, shutdown

i have previously had the issue of ubuntu 18.04 staying stuck on shutdown.

The solution i've implemented was changing some settings from the grub.

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="intel_idle.max_cstate=1"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

this is how the grub looks like and my laptop can now shutdown.

but now i have the issue of my speakers making a pop sound when my laptop shuts down.

i have seen some solutions for the problem, but not for ubuntu 18.04

my laptop is an Aspire E1-410-2632 acer computer with intel HD graphics, processor: Intel® Celeron(R) CPU N2820 @ 2.13GHz × 2 and i'm sharing the hard drive with windows 8-1.

please notify me if any more specs of my laptop are necessary.